# FutureBuilder with Directory(previous/path).list runs second time for previous directory

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

Cosider this simplified example:

```
class _MyExampleState extends State<MyExample> {

  String home = "/storage/emulated/0/Home";
  String folder = "/storage/emulated/0/Home/Folder";

  String currentPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Home";

  updatePath() {
    setState(() {
      currentPath = currentPath == home ? folder : home;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: Directory(currentPath).list().toList(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print('future builder is running for $currentPath');

            var data = snapshot.data;
            if (data != null && data.isNotEmpty) {
              
              // filter out only mp3 files
              var items = data.map((e) => e.path).where((el) =>
                  el.endsWith('.mp3')).toList();
              
              print('number of mp3s found: ${items.length}');

              if (!currentPath.endsWith('/Home')) {
                items = ['...', ...items];
              } else {
                items = ['Folder', ...items];
              }

              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var item = items[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (!item.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                          updatePath();
                        }
                      },
                      title: Text(item),
                    );
                  }
              );
            } else {
              return const Text('nothing was found');
            }
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There 5 mp3 files in `/Home`, and 10 in `/Home/Folder`. 
After I start the app, and tap `Folder`, log says:

> I/flutter ( 6367): future builder is running for /storage/emulated/0/Home/Folder 
> I/flutter ( 6367): number of mp3s found: 5 
> I/flutter ( 6367): future builder is running for /storage/emulated/0/Home/Folder 
> I/flutter ( 6367): number of mp3s found: 10

Then after tap on `...` (to go back to `/Home`):

> I/flutter ( 6367): future builder is running for /storage/emulated/0/Home 
> I/flutter ( 6367): number of mp3s found: 10 
> I/flutter ( 6367): future builder is running for /storage/emulated/0/Home 
> I/flutter ( 6367): number of mp3s found: 5

So despite actually seeing the right directory to be queried, it still queryies the previous one first. What's the problem here?

***UPD: complete almost copy-paste example here: https://pastebin.com/AdAvAC5c